# Lagrange's Theorem of Groups stated differently? I don't understand the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From my limited experience with group theory I don't know what this is saying.

First, I understand Lagrange's theorem to be

> For some group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, $|G|=k|H|$ where $k$ is the number of distinct left coset of $H$ in $G$.

and the left coset of $H$ in $G$ being, take element $g \in G$ and consider $gH$, where the operation is as defined for $G$ and $H$ (be it multiplication, addition whatever).
Then the $gH$ are left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Now, this is as far as I am familiar with. Here is the problem that is getting me baffled

> Find $(\mathbb{Z}:5 \mathbb{Z})$ where $(G:H)$ is the number of distinct left coset of $H$ in $G$.

First I assume this operation is addition, not multiplication or some other operation. Issue is, isn't the order of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $+$ going to be well, infinite? It's the set of integers under addition right? Then, well, how can I find the number of different left cosets? shouldn't they also be infinite too?

But, the answer goes on to explain it as follows and I am just literally trying to put my jaw back in position.

> Since $\mathbb{Z}=5 \mathbb{Z} \cup (1+5 \mathbb{Z}) \cup (2+5 \mathbb{Z}) \cup (3+5 \mathbb{Z})+(4+5 \mathbb{Z})$, we have $(\mathbb{Z}:5 \mathbb{Z})=5$

...What in heaven's name is this series of unions of..left cosets? I mean, $5 \mathbb{Z}=\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4}\}$ so adding some $n$, say $1$ then, would make it $1+5 \mathbb{Z}=\{1+\bar{0},1+\bar{1},1+\bar{2},1+\bar{3},1+\bar{4}\}=\{\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4},\bar{0}\} = 5 \mathbb{Z}$, no? Since take any equivalence class, $\bar{0}$ which is essentially $0,\pm5,\pm10...$ so adding $1$ to each just gives $\bar{1}$.

So then, every single $n+5\mathbb{Z}=5 \mathbb{Z}$ and why would the unions give me the "entire set of integers?"

But I know my reasoning is wrong, since if so, I am saying that the left coset of $5 \mathbb{Z}$ under addition of $\mathbb{Z}$ is basically all $5 \mathbb{Z}$. Meaning, only $1$ type of left coset. Meaning, by Lagrange that the order of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $1 \times 5=5$.

However, the *actual* answer I still find ridiculous because in a similar manner, it is claiming, by Lagrange, that the size of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $5 \times 5 =25$ which is in no way acceptable.

Can someone explain to me what is going on with this? the order of $\mathbb{Z}$ means the "number of elements in", yes? How is it not infinity then? And even if you can convince me it's not, how is $\mathbb{Z}=5 \mathbb{Z} \cup (1+5 \mathbb{Z}) \cup (2+5 \mathbb{Z}) \cup (3+5 \mathbb{Z})+(4+5 \mathbb{Z})$ true at all? How does this even relate to Lagrange's theorem? Isn't there only $1$ type of left coset in this case?

Comment: $5{\mathbb Z}$ is not a finite set, but an infinite set consisting of all multiples of $5$. Thats is $5{\mathbb Z} = \{5n : n \in {\mathbb Z}\}$.

Comment: Fundamentally Lagrange;s Theorem is a result about fine groups $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That solved it like dominos, thanks.it makes sense then